# Declaring functions and memory optimization in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, memory-management

I'm declaring a function this way :

```
function clearScrollViewCont(elm,indx,array){

            elm.removeAllChildren();
        $.scrollView.scrollViewCont.remove(elm);
        elm = null;     
}
```

then i call it inside a forEach function :

```
$.scrollView.scrollViewCont.getchildren().forEach(clearScrollViewCont);
```

All the previous code is inside another big function so when this big function is removed from the memory all its content will be cleared as well but i don't know what could be the faster way to free memory. I'm used to null every variable which i don't need anymore (even it's written inside a big function) but now, i wonder about clearing memory from declared functions 
In my previous code, declaring the 'clearScrollViewCont' function that way won't let me to null it later. On the other side, if i declare it this way :

```
 var clearScrollViewCont =  function (elm,indx,array){

        elm.removeAllChildren();
        $.scrollView.scrollViewCont.remove(elm);
        elm = null;     
    }
```

i can null it later (simply by nulling the 'clearScrollViewCont' variable) but i don't know if this itself takes more memory space then the first way as now i'm declaring a variable in addition to the function.

What are really pros and cons of each way ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion both ways take up the same amount of space. It shouldn't really matter whether you declare a function like:

```
function clearScrollViewCont(elm,indx,array){}
```

or

```
var clearScrollViewCont = function(elm,indx,array){}
```

In both cases a Function object is created, which is callable by its name:  `clearScrollViewCont(...);` 
Remember that JavaScript Functions are also objects: ([Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function))
Therefore both ways take up the same amount of space in my opinion.